# Rewriting the equation of motion as a system of first order differential equation

Tags: orbital-mechanics, mathematics

I am required to rewrite the equation

$$\ddot{\mathbf{r}} = - \frac{\mu}{r^3} \mathbf{r}$$

as a first order differential equation. How do I go about doing this?

I understand how this equation was derived from the original

$$\mathbf{F}_{21}=-\frac{G m_1 m_2}{r^2}\hat{\mathbf{u}}_r$$

but I am struggling to find information on the process of attaining $\dot{\mathbf{r}}$ from the above equations.

Comment: Who is requiring you? If this is a homework question make sure to consider these points. Which are also relevant for answers if this indeed a homework question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 3):

Given a scalar function $f(x)$ that is described as an $n^{th}$ order differential equation can be converted to a first order $n$ dimensional vector differential equation. For example, suppose
$$\begin{aligned}
f'(x) &= g(f(x), x) \\
f''(x) &= h(f(x), f'(x), x)
\end{aligned}$$
The solution is to make an augmented function $\vec u(x)$ such that $u[1](x) = f(x)$ and $u[2](x) = f'(x)$. The same can be applied to a vector function $\vec r(t)$. In the case of gravitation, we the result is a six vector, where $u[1](t) = r_x(t)$, $u[2](t) = r_y(t)$, $u[3](t) = r_z(t)$, $u[4](t) = v_x(t)$, $u[5](t) = v_y(t)$, and $u[6](t) = v_z(t)$. The time derivatives of the first three elements are simply the velocity vector, while the time derivatives of the last three elements are given by Newton's law of gravitation.

Answer (score 2):

R double dot is three second-order equations.  The standard trick to convert it into six first-order equations is to introduce velocity, so R dot = V and V dot = what R double dot was.  Then, writing a six-element state vector as R conjoined with V, you can write the six equations in matrix form as something like

$$\begin{bmatrix}\dot{r}_x\\ \dot{r}_y\\ \dot{r}_z\\ \dot{v}_x\\ \dot{v}_y\\ \dot{v}_z\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ & \cdots & & & & \\ & & \cdots & & &  \\ & & & \cdots & &  \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}r_x\\ r_y\\ r_z\\ v_x\\ v_y\\ v_z\end{bmatrix}
$$

Filling in the blanks may require some rearrangement of variables and application of the chain rule, depending on which coordinates and additional perturbing terms you are using.

Comment: That matrix form is a linearization of the nonlinear 2nd order gravitational equation. It does not answer the question.